# Flutter: Widget Tree

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, widget

There are two Widgets I created, and a main Widget. But i am getting an Error:

> "**package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart': Failed assertion: line
> 1899**"

**Main Widget:**

```
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Drawer(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              buildHeader(), 
              buildMenu()
              ],
          ),
        );
      }
```

**First Widget:**

```
Widget buildHeader() {
          return const Center(
            child: Card(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 300,
                height: 100,
                child: Center(child: Text('Elevated Card')),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
```

**Second Widget:**

```
     Widget buildMenu() {
       return Drawer(
           child: FutureBuilder<List<Menu>>(
         future: listMenus,
         builder: (context, snapshot) {
           if (snapshot.hasData) {
             return ListView.builder(
               itemCount: (snapshot.data as List<Menu>).length,
               itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                 var menu = (snapshot.data as List<Menu>)[index];
                 return Padding(
                   padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1, horizontal: 4),
                   child: Card(
                     child: ListTile(
                       onTap: () {
                         // print(listMenus[index]);
                       },
                       title: Text(menu.folder),
                     ),
                   ),
                 );
               },
             );
           } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
             return Center(
               child: Text("${snapshot.error}"),
             );
           }
           return const Center(
             child: CircularProgressIndicator(
               backgroundColor: Colors.cyanAccent,
             ),
           );
         },
       ));
     }
```

.....................................................................

Comment: Where are you using this main widget, can you include from MaterialApp

Comment: How can i include ?

Comment: Follow bellow snippet structure, it will solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main widget is returning a drawer and the second widget is also returning a drawer. In second widget replace the drawer with an Expanded widget or SizedBox of specific height and width

**EDIT**

I checked your codes with some dummy data and getting the result as expected

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Center(child: DemoClass()));
  }
}

class DemoClass extends StatelessWidget {
  DemoClass({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            buildHeader(),
            buildMenu(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget buildHeader() {
  return const Center(
    child: Card(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 300,
        height: 100,
        child: Center(child: Text('Elevated Card')),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget buildMenu() {
  return Expanded(
      child: FutureBuilder<List<Menu>>(
        future: listMenus,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: (snapshot.data as List<Menu>).length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                Menu menu = (snapshot.data as List<Menu>)[index];
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1, horizontal: 4),
                  child: Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      onTap: () {
                        // print(listMenus[index]);
                      },
                      title: Text(menu.folder),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text("${snapshot.error}"),
            );
          }
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.cyanAccent,
            ),
          );
        },
      ));
}
```

[image: preview]

Comment: Right, that was one of my mistakes, thanks.

Comment: Did it work as expected?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't show anything on the screen.

Comment: In the scaffold you can add a SizedBox(height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.5) Then as a child of this sized box add the Column widget you have

Comment: The Error is : Creates a fixed size box. The [width] and [height] parameters can be null to indicate that the size of the box should not be constrained in the corresponding dimension. 

And The Code:
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.5
      );
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            buildHeader(),
            Expanded(child: buildMenu()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

Comment: I am getting just white page. I guess should use StateFullWidget but I couldnt convert StateFullWidget. And ı want to call the DemoClass in Main as a widget

Comment: Drag from the left side  to see the drawer

Comment: thanks bro , I forgot to edit main content. So I thought the data was not coming.

Comment: Can we fix it in a way that comes from the left via a 3-line icon at the top left of the homepage? The white page confuses me.

Comment: Add an appbar to the scaffold. The drawer icon is handled inside that. Its called leading icon in appbar

Answer (score 0):

Follow the snippet and dont need multiple drawer. And handle overflow by wrapping ListView with `Expanded`

```dart
return Scaffold(
  drawer: Drawer(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        buildHeader(),
         buildMenu(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

```dart
 Widget buildMenu() { ....
    return  Expanded(child: ListView.builder(
```

Snippet structure

```dart
class SG extends StatefulWidget {
  SG({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SG> createState() => _SGState();
}

class _SGState extends State<SG> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            buildHeader(),
            buildMenu(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildHeader() {
    return const Center(
      child: Card(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 300,
          height: 100,
          child: Center(child: Text('Elevated Card')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  
Widget buildMenu() {
  return FutureBuilder<List<Menu>>(
    future: listMenus,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: (snapshot.data as List<Menu>).length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              var menu = (snapshot.data as List<Menu>)[index];
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1, horizontal: 4),
                child: Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    onTap: () {
                      // print(listMenus[index]);
                    },
                    title: Text(menu.folder),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Center(
          child: Text("${snapshot.error}"),
        );
      }
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          backgroundColor: Colors.cyanAccent,
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: This is looking very well. But buildMenu() is missing somethings.

Comment: You can have FutureBuilder, just remove its `Drawer(`

Comment: I am not able to do.

Comment: ok try Now ,,, .

Comment: Tried but I am new in Flutter. If I continue to fail, I will quit.

Comment: Good things take time, You need to understand the concept 1st, rest is up to you, either you are passionate or not. Start from [cookbook](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook)

Comment: Thanks, but i will probably keep asking questions here again. :)

Comment: you are always welcome to ask question showing your effort and asking specific question. You can about [asking good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)